# Decrease size of video in android with minimal loss of quality

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-compression

I am recording video using camera intent and getting displaying it in a videiview. Now i want to upload it, But it is very big in size. I want to compress it using FFMPEG as I found the many article and in SO also, but i didn't find any clear article with codes.

Can anyone help me with ffmpeg code ?
Is there any other way to do it in android ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/fishwjy/VideoCompressor

Comment: I have downloaded the VideoCompressor-master.zip how to add its dependency ? @Quicklearner

Comment: simply copy project in your project

Comment: I have to unzip it and put it in app/libs/ ?

Comment: yes and import project then check what to copy in your project

Comment: https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor     check this library

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
-b:v 5000k -minrate 5000k -maxrate 5000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -preset superfast
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
String cmd = "-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast " + newFile.getPath();
```